# Wordpress localization - gettext and git

Tags: translation, localization, l10n

We're about to start working on localization of a highly customized wordpress theme with over 200 php files. We're using git for version control. Are there any particular hints or warnings we should know about?

Do we just stick the po/mo files in there with the theme? We're probably going to try to use a tool like WPML or Codestyling Localization. Do they store everything in files or to they mess about with wpdb?

Answer (score 2):

Use the CS Localization plugin and generate the po/mo files, thats all. Save the file also in the repo of git and ready. The performance of the theme is not so high, if you have the strings inside the php-files, but only so it is possible to create different languages for the themes. mo/po files is also ascii files and its give no problems with git or WP.